# What is the point of the spikes on the Raspberry Pi?

Tags: hardware

I was looking at my Raspberry Pi recently, and noticed strange spikes protruding on the top of it (They are the ones next to the yellow input thingy)

[image: Pi Pic]

What are they used for? What is their purpose?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are referring to the general purpose I/O lines (or GPIO). You can do [all sorts of things with them](http://www.raspberrypi.org/archives/tag/gpio). Basically they are for reading sensors and activating additional electronics such as motors, actuators, solenoids, other digital electronic circuits, etc.

Answer (score 4):

[You can find allot of interesting things about the Raspberry Pi in this PDF](http://d4c027c89b30561298bd-484902fe60e1615dc83faa972a248000.r12.cf3.rackcdn.com/supporting_materials/Raspberry%20Pi%20Start%20Guide.pdf)

[image]

**And this a great reference for the GPIO HEADERS pin numbers and their functions.**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is a great deal of detail on elinux about them [here](http://elinux.org/Rpi_Low-level_peripherals), as well as a fairly large list of boards which plug on top of them to add more features for the Raspberry Pi [here](http://elinux.org/RPi_Expansion_Boards).

They are a great way to make first steps from programming on its own into software controlling hardware (talking to electronics).